# Unsure how to resolve SQL error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to run the script below but am getting an error...

> Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 58
>   The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Is anybody able to tell me where I am going wrong. Please be gentle as I am new to all this. :)

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT
   c.address_number as address_number,
   c.contact_number as contact_number,
   c.label_name as contact_name,
   a.address as address,
   a.postcode as postcode,
   s.source as source,
   s.source_desc as source_desc,
   m.joined as member_join_date,
   m.membership_card_expires as member_expiry_date,
   o.payment_method as payment_method,
   pf.payment_frequency_desc as payment_frequency_desc,
   pf.frequency as payment_frequency,
   c.std_code as std_code,
   c.telephone as phone_number,
   gift_aid = CASE
                WHEN gad.declaration_number IS NOT NULL then 'Y' else null end,
   cp.first_payment_date as first_payment_date,
   cp.last_payment_date as last_payment_date,
   -- NUMBER OF DONATIONS IN THE LAST 12 MONTHS GOES HERE --
   cp.value_of_payments as total_donation_amount
FROM
   contacts c
INNER JOIN 
   contact_addresses ca ON c.contact_number = ca.contact_number 
                        AND c.address_number = ca.address_number
INNER JOIN 
   addresses a ON ca.address_number = a.address_number 
INNER JOIN 
   sources s ON c.source = s.source
INNER JOIN 
   contact_suppressions cs ON c.contact_number = cs.contact_number
INNER JOIN 
   orders o ON c.contact_number = o.contact_number
INNER JOIN 
   members m ON c.contact_number = m.contact_number
INNER JOIN 
   contact_categories cc ON c.contact_number = cc.contact_number
INNER JOIN 
   payment_frequencies pf ON o.payment_frequency = pf.payment_frequency
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   gift_aid_declarations gad ON c.contact_number = gad.contact_number 
                             AND (start_date IS NULL OR start_date < GETDATE())
INNER JOIN 
   contact_performances cp ON c.contact_number = cp.contact_number
WHERE
   -- EXCLUSIONS --
   c.status NOT IN ('DECD','AN','DU','GONE') AND
   c.contact_number NOT IN (SELECT contact_number FROM contact_suppressions 
                            WHERE mailing_suppression IN ('NOMA','APP','DATA')) AND
   c.contact_number NOT IN (SELECT contact_number FROM contact_categories 
                            WHERE activity IN ('MAJDON', 'PATRON', 'PCD11', 'PCT', 
                                               'PCAD12', 'PCAD13', 'PCFI13', 
                                               'PCHR12', 'PCIA12', 'PCNH12',
                                               'PCSL13', 'PCSK13', 'PCTC13')) AND 
   ca.historical = 'N' AND
   -- MEMEBRSHIP NOT CANCELLED --
   m.cancellation_reason IS NULL
ORDER BY
    address_number, contact_number, contact_name, address, postcode, source, source_desc, member_join_date,
member_expiry_date, payment_method, payment_frequency_desc, payment_frequency, std_code, phone_number, gift_aid,      first_payment_date, last_payment_date, total_donation_amount
```

Comment: Please identify which column(s) is/are `text`, `ntext`, or `image`.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out which of the columns you are working with are text, ntext, or image datatype columns. As per the error message, you are using columns of this datatype to "sort or "compare". In this query, that'd be in the WHERE clause, the ON clauses of your joins, the ORDER BY clause, the ORDER BY clause, or possibly within that one CASE statement.

Based solely on the colunn names, I'd guess it's `source` or `gift_aid`, but it is impossible to determine without reviewing the schema.

Comment: Just to mention, in SQL 2012 you *really* shouldn't be using the text, ntext, or image datatypes. I'd hazard a guess that you've inherited a database created years ago, making this issue beyond your control.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates line 58 which is the "Cancellation_reason IS NULL"

Maybe you can apply a LEFT() to get to a character string, then have it tested as null, something like

```
LEFT( m.cancellation_reason, 1 ) IS NULL
```

So here, I only care about the first character of the cancellation reason.  if it is null, won't it return as null?,